# "National coverage" or "nationwide coverage"

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

"National coverage" or "nationwide coverage" which is more correct? for instance "we have a national coverage of three locations"

Comment: _"National"_ and _"Nationwide"_ are two different things. They can mean the same thing in certain contexts, but they are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 2):

**National** tends to mean **to the nation**

> The presidential debates have received **national coverage**
>   *The presidential debates were nationally televised*

whereas, **nationwide** tends to mean **across the nation**

> The major networks have given **nationwide coverage** to college graduations
>   *College gradutations across the country were reported on*
>
> Verizon now has 4G **nationwide coverage**
>   *4G is available across the country*

In your example,

> national coverage **of** three locations

doesn't really make sense, however

> nationwide coverage **from** three locations

means you have three locations scattered across the nation.

Answer (score 1):

national = at the level of the nation (as distinct from local or regional)

nationwide = extending across the country

Let's say that an important political rally is happening in a particular city. Reporters from all parts of the country have come there in order to cover the story. We would say that the rally is receiving **national coverage**. When the story has been aired in cities throughout the country, so that people everywhere have learned about it, we would say that the story was seen **nationwide**.

Now let's say a particular news corporation claims to have reporters and local syndicates in every city throughout the nation. They could claim to offer **nationwide coverage** of the news.

Let's say a local newspaper has stories mostly about the region, and very few stories about events affecting the entire nation.  We could say that the newspaper has a regional focus, not a **national** focus.

If a telecommunications company claims to have **nationwide coverage**, it means they have erected communications towers throughout the country, so that their customers can travel anywhere in the country and still use their phones.